# Передать значения из события onAfterChange в свойство компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события, компоненты

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Необходимо при перемещении ползунка событием `onAfterChange` отобразить значения `minDisplayValue` и `maxDisplayValue` под слайдером в другом компоненте. Но не даёт, из за того что он не видит переменные в событии. Я пытался объявлять глобально, тоже не помогает.

````
interface SliderProps {
    valuesCv?: SliderMarks,
    minValue?: number,
    maxValue?: number,
}

const Slider: FC<SliderProps> = ({ valuesCv, minValue, maxValue }) => {
    
    const onChange = (value: number | [number, number]) => {
        console.log('onChange', value)
    }

    const onAfterChange = (target: [number, number]) => {
        const minDisplayValue = target[0];
        const maxDisplayValue = target[1];
        console.log('onafterchange', minDisplayValue, maxDisplayValue)
    }

    return <>
        <SliderA
            range
            marks={changeKeys}
            defaultValue={[minValue ?? 0, maxValue ?? maxValueChange]}
            max={maxValue ?? maxValueChange}
            min={minValue ?? 0}
            onChange={onChange}
            onAfterChange={onAfterChange}
        />

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <SliderValueRange
                value={minDisplayValue}
                unit={'cv'}
            />
            <SliderValueRange
                value={maxDisplayValue}
                unit={'cv'}
            />
        </div>
    </>
}```
````

Comment: Заведи в общем родителе стейт... Меняй его в нужном компоненте. Стейт пропсами передавай в другой компонент...

Comment: @ksa, Дай Бог Вам здоровья! Напишите, пожалуйста, это не комментарием, что бы я отметил ответ как правильный

Comment: Помогло и ладно, от меня не убудет. Хочешь плюсануть - так у меня тут еще много сообщений. ;)

Comment: Вопрос решён комментарием от @ksa